# C# vs C# Compiler

Tags: c#, roslyn

Does C# 6 means "Roslyn" ?

Is it the same thing C# and C# Compiler ?
There is a lot of article about C# and new C# features, but what is C# ?
It is the C# Compiler or do I need to know something else about this ?

And how can see which version of my visual studio using to compile the code ?
I know that for example vs 2015 using C# 6 by default but how does it manages that, any configuration file or something else ?

Can I see the commands visualstudio using while compiling my code for example at Output Window ? (Something like "cl.exe ... main.c")

What are the paths of every single C# compiler ?

Comment: C#6 is a language specification. You can write your own compiler for it. Roslyn is Microsoft's compiler, and the compiler most people will use.

Comment: With *C# 6* I normally mean the syntax. Clearly then you need a C# 6 compiler, but theorically you don't need to use Microsoft's one. Mono compiler supports the C# 6.0 syntax.

Comment: From the [mono page](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/languages/csharp/): *The Mono C# compiler is considered feature complete for C# 1.0, C# 2.0, C# 3.0, C# 4.0, C# 5.0 and **C# 6.0***

Comment: Please don't post answers as comments. The question can't be marked as resolved that way. You also get more reputation points for doing it properly. I would've upvoted the answer @Rob but I'm holding back on voting up the comment, as much as I like it. ;)

Comment: @BernhardHofmann I don't feel like that comment was worthy of an answer, and I don't have the time to write a fully fleshed out answer

Comment: @BernhardHofmann Me too :-) You are free to write a response with my piece of response :-)

Comment: @Rob Except that the last published specification is for C# 5.0. Effectively, C# 6.0 is currently defined by what the Roslyn 1.0 compiler does.

Comment: @svick A perfect example as to why it was merely a comment and not an answer as suggested ;)

Comment: Can you limit your question post to only one question? If you have more than one question, create separate questions for that.

Comment: @PJvG Generally, I agree with that sentiment. But in this case, the questions are closely related and probably not worthy a question of their own. So I think this question is fine in that regard.

Comment: @HakamFostok [Please don't use code formatting for non-code.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254995/41071)

Comment: @svick it is not code formatting, which I used

Comment: @HakamFostok You used backticks and [the help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) says: "Use backticks (in the upper left corner of most keyboards) to create an inline `<code>` span". So it is exactly what you used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Does C# 6 mean "Roslyn"?

Effectively, yes. There is no official specification ([an unofficial draft](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/tree/master/spec) exists, hopefully, [that will improve in the near future](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/64)). [The Mono C# compiler](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/languages/csharp/) does support C# 6.0, but as far as I know, it's being replaced with the Roslyn compiler.

> Is it the same thing C# and C# Compiler?

In theory, there is a difference between the C# language (as defined by its specification, if one exists), and the C# compiler developed by Microsoft (a.k.a. Roslyn). In practice, they correspond very closely together. C# 6.0 is the same thing as "the language supported by version 1.0 of the Roslyn compiler" or "the version of C# supported by VS 2015". (And the same applies to C# 7.0, Roslyn 2.0 and VS 2017.)

> And how can see which version of my visual studio using to compile the code?

Unless you do something unusual, like compiling Roslyn yourself and using that in an instance of VS, VS uses a version of the C# compiler that was released along with it. That means C# 6.0 for VS 2015 and C# 7.0 for VS 2017. For a full list, see [this table in the Wikipedia article about C#](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_(programming_language)#Versions) (look at the first and last column).

You can also make a newer compiler compile using a previous version of the language. To do this in VS, go to project properties → Build → Advanced → Language Version.

> I know that for example vs 2015 using C# 6 by default but how does it manages that, any configuration file or something else?

[The C# extension for Visual Studio](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/tree/master/src/VisualStudio) includes a built-in C# compiler, used for things like IntelliSense.

To actually build a project, VS uses MSBuild, which is configured using .targets files. Specifically, if you want to set your own path to csc.exe, you can use the `CscToolPath` property, e.g. on the command line: `msbuild /p:CscToolPath=my\csc\path` or by adding `<PropertyGroup><CscToolPath>my\csc\path</CscToolPath></PropertyGroup>` to your .csproj file.

> Can I see the commands Visual Studio is using while compiling my code for example at Output Window?

One way to do that is to run `msbuild` (possibly with `/t:rebuild` to ensure the compiler is actually run) from the Developer Command Prompt for VS.

For example, for a new C# console application project created in VS 2017, the output for me is:

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.1.548.43366
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 27. 3. 2017 16:39:39.
Project "C:\code\tmp\ConsoleApp2\ConsoleApp2.csproj" on node 1 (rebuild target(s)).
CoreClean:
  Deleting file "C:\code\tmp\ConsoleApp2\bin\Debug\ConsoleApp2.exe.config".
  Deleting file "C:\code\tmp\ConsoleApp2\bin\Debug\ConsoleApp2.exe".
  Deleting file "C:\code\tmp\ConsoleApp2\bin\Debug\ConsoleApp2.pdb".
  Deleting file "C:\code\tmp\ConsoleApp2\obj\Debug\ConsoleApp2.csprojResolveAssemblyReferen
  ce.cache".
  Deleting file "C:\code\tmp\ConsoleApp2\obj\Debug\ConsoleApp2.exe".
  Deleting file "C:\code\tmp\ConsoleApp2\obj\Debug\ConsoleApp2.pdb".
GenerateBindingRedirects:
  No suggested binding redirects from ResolveAssemblyReferences.
GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-t
o-date with respect to the input files.
CoreCompile:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\bin\Roslyn\cs
  c.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /platform:anycpu32bitpreferred /errorreport:
  prompt /warn:4 /define:DEBUG;TRACE /highentropyva+ /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Ref
  erence Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /referen
  ce:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\
  mscorlib.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework
  \.NETFramework\v4.6.2\System.Core.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assem
  blies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /refere
  nce:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2
  \System.Data.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Frame
  work\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\System.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemb
  lies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\System.Net.Http.dll" /reference:"C:\Program
   Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\System.Xml.dll
  " /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramewo
  rk\v4.6.2\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /debug+ /debug:full /filealign:512 /optimize- /out:obj\Deb
  ug\ConsoleApp2.exe /ruleset:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterpri
  se\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\\Rule Sets\MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset" /subsyste
  mversion:6.00 /target:exe /utf8output Program.cs Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs "C:\Users\Svi
  ck\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2.AssemblyAttributes.cs"
  Using shared compilation with compiler from directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft V
  isual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\bin\Roslyn
_CopyAppConfigFile:
  Copying file from "App.config" to "bin\Debug\ConsoleApp2.exe.config".
CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
  Copying file from "obj\Debug\ConsoleApp2.exe" to "bin\Debug\ConsoleApp2.exe".
  ConsoleApp2 -> C:\code\tmp\ConsoleApp2\bin\Debug\ConsoleApp2.exe
  Copying file from "obj\Debug\ConsoleApp2.pdb" to "bin\Debug\ConsoleApp2.pdb".
Done Building Project "C:\code\tmp\ConsoleApp2\ConsoleApp2.csproj" (rebuild target(s)).


Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.33
```

Notice the `CoreCompile` section, which shows the command used to compile the project.

Another way to get the same output is to [change the MSBuild verbosity in VS](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/msbuild/2005/09/28/cranking-up-the-build-verbosity-in-the-ide/) to Normal, Build (or Rebuild) and then look at the Output window.

> What are the paths of every single C# compiler?

You can find out what is the location of the csc.exe corresponding to a certain version of VS by opening the Developer Command Prompt for that version of VS and running `where csc`. For me, this prints `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\csc.exe` (which is version 1.3.1.60616) for VS 2015 Update 3 and `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn\csc.exe` (version 2.0.0.61501) for VS 2017.

The reason why the paths are different is because VS 2017 changed where its various components are installed.

In both cases, a second line of `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe` is also printed, which is the old pre-Roslyn C# 5.0 compiler (version 4.6.1586.0).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and detailed reply. It really contains very useful informations for me